# Show only one side of 3D object Threejs

Tags: three.js

I have pb with threeJS obj, I loaded 3d object and want show only one side of this object not full,

```
  export function loadObjWithMaterial(mtlFile, objFile, imgPath) {
  let mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setTexturePath(imgPath);
 
  let url = mtlFile;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mtlLoader.load(url, materials => {
      materials.preload();
      let objLoader = new OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
      objLoader.load(objFile, object => resolve(object));
      objLoader.load(objFile, function(object){
          resolve(object)
      });
    });
  });
}
```

and now I tried to show only one side of the object and add this one

```
mtlLoader.setMaterialOptions({side: 1});
```

seems now it should show only one side of object but its not.

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNTCh.png)

[what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3MY0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. Anyway 'THREE.FrontSide' is the default value for the side property.

```
mtlLoader.setMaterialOptions( { side : THREE.FrontSide } );
```

[Here you can see the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/MTLLoader)

Comment: this what i did mtlLoader.setMaterialOptions({side: 1}); same  THREE.FrontSide =1

Comment: @user2955933, I understood that. The images you shared doesn't clearly state your requirement. Please specify the problem :)